# PyQt ScrollArea not showing scroll bars

Tags: qt, pyqt, scrollbar

I am using Qt Creator 3.1.2 to design a GUI, that has a ScrollArea to display a list of Widgets (just QLabels for now).

In the object Tree, I have a QScrollArea containing a QWidget containing a QVBoxLayout. For the ScrollArea, I have set verticalScrollBarPolicy to AsNeeded, and widgetResizable to On. For the Layout, I have set SizeConstraint to SetMinimumSize.

In my Python program, I load the GUI and then try and populate the Layout with widgets like so:

```
sa = self.findChild(QtGui.QVBoxLayout, "scrollList")
for i in range(1,40):
    l = QtGui.QLabel("hello %s"%i)
    l.setFixedHeight(40)
    sa.addWidget(l)
```

Widgets 1-6 appear, with correct size, and don't appear to be squashed or anything. However there is no scroll bar, and I cant scroll the window to view the other widgets below. I have tried forcing the scroll bars to appear, but it appears deactivated and I still cant scroll the window.

What can I do to get the scroll bars to appear and the window to scroll?

This is the generated XML for the ScrollArea:

```
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>461</width>
      <height>291</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::WinPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>457</width>
       <height>287</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>-1</x>
        <y>-1</y>
        <width>461</width>
        <height>291</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="scrollList" stretch="">
       <property name="sizeConstraint">
        <enum>QLayout::SetMinimumSize</enum>
       </property>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
```

Comment: Does "other widgets" mean you have more than 6 widgets?

Comment: @Tay2510 yes as you can see I am adding 40 of them.

Comment: this can help [link](http://nealbuerger.com/2013/11/pyside-qvboxlayout-with-qscrollarea/)

Comment: Updated Aleksander's link: https://web.archive.org/web/20180819091554/https://nealbuerger.com/2013/11/pyside-qvboxlayout-with-qscrollarea/